# Can a trigger be used to alert me when a specific table is updated in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I have a database that has a variety of users and I'd like to receive an update or alert when a specific table is updated.

Is this possible?

Comment: You probably want to do this in your application, not at the database level. Your code knows what tables its updating (and more importantly, what that means (i.e. adding user, removing user, banning user)), and can act accordingly at that time.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. This makes it much easier.

Comment: mysql cannot send emails with external plugins. You can easily put an "update" trigger on the table, but without plugins, there's no way to actually send any kind of notification.

Comment: Can something be built directly into the app with PHP, to watch the application's updates, and not at the DB level?

Comment: You could insert a log in another table with a trigger and regularly crawl that other table